# Video clarity with my code is bit low as compared to recording with Android camera

Tags: android, video-recording

In my application I recorded a video and then playing. For recording a video I used the below code

```
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); 
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);



    File MyMedia=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"Directory");
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(MyMedia.getAbsolutePath()+"/filename.mp4");
```

It is working fine but video clarity is bit low compare with another video which is recorded by native recorder. Please tell me the solution for how to set video clarity same as native recorder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set frameRate and videoSize.

```
recorder.setVideoFrameRate();
recorder.setVideoSize();
```